# Is there any mathematical patterns or logic in the Qur'an?

Tags: quran

I read a website some time ago and there was all sorts of patterns in the book as well as different types of logic in it. Can someone elaborate please?

Answer (score 12):

Basically no. What people discover are spurious patterns, which are present in any work.

One way to do this is by running your computer looking for a 1-in-a-million possibility, then present what it finds without mentioning all the failed attempts.

Pattens have be found in e.g.:

- [The Bible/Torah](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_code)
- [The works of Shakespeare](http://www.wondersandmarvels.com/2012/12/shakespeares-secrets-a-hidden-cipher-in-literatures-greatest-works.html)
- War and Peace, and the lyrics to Ice Ice Baby (see John Safran vs. God, [episode 7](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Safran_vs_God))

People are more likely to believe these patterns are meaningful in books with more mysticism surrounding them.

It's also worth noting an example of how these findings are fudged to fit the pattern the author is seeking:

> By examining the statistics presented by those who have published these numbers, we find that they did not get the numbers of some phrases right, and some of them have been selective in the way they counted the words, and that is so that they might reach the conclusion they want and that they think is in the Book of Allaah. -- [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/69741)

Comment: I really don't like it when people try to interpret the Quran in a way that is consistent with what they believe or want to believe.